# How to ensure resultproperty is set by last ant target?

Tags: java, ant, exit, exit-code

So here's the situation. I have a target called `ErrorHelp`, which takes the value of `exitCode` and passes it into a function that prints out a message based on that value. Each of a number of other targets then have `exitCode` as their `resultproperty`, so say they exit with code 4, then `exitCode` is 4 and `ErrorHelp` passes the value 4.

Running, for example,

```
>> Target1 ErrorHelp
```

gives the correct value to `ErrorHelp`. However, let's take the following situation. I run `Target1` in such a way that I know it will return the value 1; I run `Target2` in such a way that I know it will return 2. One would hope that running

```
>> Target1 Target2 ErrorHelp
```

would result in ErrorHelp running with value 2; this is not the case, and instead runs with value 1. Can a second, same-line target not reset the value of `exitCode`? If not, is there a way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

**EDIT - providing some code:**

Let's say `Target1` is defined as

```
<target name="Target1">
    <java classname="path_to_file/Target1" fork="true" resultproperty="exitCode">
        <classpath>
            <path location="path_to_jar/required_jar.jar"/>
        </classpath>
    </java>
    <antcall target="ErrorHelp"/>
</target>
```

and `Target2` is

```
<target name="Target2">
    <java classname="path_to_file/Target2" fork="true" resultproperty="exitCode">
        <classpath>
            <path location="path_to_jar/required_jar.jar"/>
        </classpath>
    </java>
    <antcall target="ErrorHelp"/>
</target>
```

(identical in structure, but calling a different Java file). `ErrorHelp` would then be

```
<target name="ErrorHelp">
    <java classname="path_to_file/ErrorCodeHelp" fork="true">
        <classpath>
            <path location="path_to_jar/required_jar.jar"/>
        </classpath>
        <arg value="-exitcode=${exitCode}"/>
    </java>
</target>
```

In the situation where I call

```
>> Target1 Target2 ErrorHelp
```

knowing that `Target1` returns 1 and `Target2` returns 2, `ErrorHelp` prints out the message for value 1, and not 2 as I would expect.

Comment: can you provide some code?

Comment: From the ant script or the Java side of things (i.e. what ErrorHelp actually calls)?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a "solution", but I do know why it is failing, which is something, I guess.

The problem is that exec is setting a *property* called exitCode, and in Ant, once a property is set, it cannot be changed (or unset). My hack work-around for this situation is to use a timestamp variable to create unique property names for each run of a task. (This is easier to do in a scriptdef block than with xml tag tasks, but the concept is the same.  You'll probably need to use Variables from ant-contrib to make this work.)

This is a very, very lame work-around to what should be a simple problem.  If you can figure out how to unset a property then you'd be able to reuse the same property name.  I have not had any luck on that front.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, **DON'T use antcall**, it's no longer required after Ant 1.6 (released in 2004).
[Macrodef](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/macrodef.html) was implemented with Ant 1.6 for that purpose.
A solution for your problem is the combination of macrodef and [local task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/local.html) (available since Ant 1.8).
Some example, a macrodef creating a property, called from different targets :

```
<project default="main">

  <target name="one">
   <print property="foo" value="bar"/>
  </target>

  <target name="two">
    <print property="foo" value="baz"/>
  </target>

  <macrodef name="print">
   <attribute name="property"/>
   <attribute name="value"/>

   <sequential>
    <local name="@{property}"/>
    <property name="@{property}" value="@{value}"/>
    <echo>$${property} = ${property}</echo>
   </sequential>
  </macrodef>

<target name="main" depends="one,two"/>
```

output :

```
one:
     [echo] ${foo} = bar
two:
     [echo] ${foo} = baz
main:
```

So in your case it would be something like :

```
  <macrodef name="foobar">
   <attribute name="class1"/>
   <attribute name="path1"/>
   <attribute name="class2"/>
   <attribute name="path2"/>
   <attribute name="rc"/>

   <sequential>
    <local name="@{rc}"/>
    <java classname="@{class1}" fork="true" resultproperty="@{rc}">
     <classpath>
     <path location="@{path1}"/>
    </classpath>
    </java>

    <java classname="@{class2}" fork="true">
     <classpath>
      <path location="@{path2}"/>
     </classpath>
     <arg value="-exitcode=${@{rc}}"/>
    </java>

    <!-- .. other stuff if needed -->

   </sequential>
  </macrodef>

    <foobar
     class1="path_to_file/Target1"
     path1="path/to/required/jar/xyz.jar"
     rc="whatever"
     class2="path_to_file/ErrorCodeHelp"
     path2="another/path/to/required/jar/abc.jar2
    />
```

The macrodef combines calling the Java class with calling Errorhelper class taking Returncode from Java class as Argument. Will work if using the same resultpropertyname in Target1 and Target2 calling the macrodef or use different names if you like. I won't repeat all the drawbacks of using antcall (performance => opens a new project scope, breaks the target dependency chain ..), just search the web.